# What is the best material for the pivot in a pivoting base?

Tags: materials

I will have a pivoting base with 3 fixed casters and a pivot in place of the fourth. I'm having trouble trying to come up with a easy to setup and no maintenance pivot. The weight requirements are not much, at most 100 kg.

I'm considering just using a straight rod down a hole in the base and also on a fixed piece of wood in the floor, with a Nylon/PE washer/spacer between them. This will be much easier to implement and shim to level if needed. I also think that this will be zero maintenance since the friction between the steel base and the nylon will be very small.

Other option is to use some hardware like those used for pivoting doors: 
[image: pivoting hardware]

This will probably be smoother due to steel ball (not sure), but it is harder to setup and shim to make the base level. I also think that it might have wear faster, but I could be wrong here.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the lateral forces. Pushing the structure around the pivot can put considerable side strain on the mounting mechanism.

Comment: Nylon likes to compress and stretch under pressure. You might do better with 3 or 4 brass washers. If too sticky, silicone spray works miracles.

Comment: @bib, this is why I'm thinking about using a straight stainless steel rod maybe 15-20mm in diameter. Since the wheels are fixed (and properly aligned to rotated around the pivot) there aren't many lateral forces in play.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I thought about using a 10mm thick (to have more resistance to compression) Nylon "washer" about 50mm in diameter in the middle of two other washers (those I might use brass or aluminum). Also, after the whole thing is assembled I can't reach it to spray silicone or any other lubricant without a full dissambly, this is why I need a zero maintenance setup.

Comment: @LuizBorges Thick is good. Some aluminum alloys act gummy if something gets in there to form scratches. I think brass is the better choice.